# Swift Mac Catalyst run function on startup if key is pressed

Tags: swift

I have a Mac Catalyst app. I like to know if there is a way to detect if a key is press while the app is launching before the view completely load. If so run a function that will clear core data

I have the follow code in my AppDelegate

```
    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        // Run backward or forward when the user presses a left or right arrow key.
        
        var didHandleEvent = false
        for press in presses {
            guard let key = press.key else { continue }
            
            /// Clear Core Data. user will lose all data saved in coredata. We use this if we have conflict in data that cause app to trash
            if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow {
                clearCoreData()
                didHandleEvent = true
            }
        }
        
        if didHandleEvent == false {
            // Didn't handle this key press, so pass the event to the next responder.
            super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
        }
    }
```